# Frida python return values and write them into file

Tags: python, frida

I'm currently using frida-python to hook onto a function in an ios application and I want the output of the function to be written in a CSV file. How do I do that?

Python script:

```
import frida, sys

script = 'script.js'
bundle = 'application'
f = open(script, "r")
s = f.read()

device = frida.get_usb_device(1000)
pid = device.spawn([bundle])
session = device.attach(pid)
script = session.create_script(s)
script.load()
device.resume(pid)
sys.stdin.read()
```

script.js

```
Interceptor.attach(intercept.implementation, {
        onEnter: function (args) {
            var instance = ObjC.chooseSync(ObjC.classes.CLASS)[0];
            send(instance.toString());
            }
        },
```

Currently, my script can only console log out the values when I have intercepted the function. Is there any ways I can return the values to python so that I can write them into CSV files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way. You change the on_message() function that handles the send() function in javascript.

i.e default on_message in python:

```
def on_message(message, data):
    if message['type'] == 'send':
        print("[* ] + message)

.... 


device = frida.get_usb_device()
pid = device.spawn(["pgk"])
session = device.attach(pid)

script = open("filepath")

drop = session.create_script(script.read())
drop.on('message', on_message)
drop.load()
time.sleep(1)  # fails without this sleep
device.resume(pid)
sys.stdin.read()
```

in your javascript you simply call

> send("Method called") // Same as console log just handled through frida

You can find the documentation for this here:

https://frida.re/docs/messages/

Comment: Yep it worked, thanks alot! But i was wondering what does `.on` do?

Comment: As far as I know from the documentation, calling on('message', on_message) is setting the python function to be triggered when a message is received from the javascript. 

This is probably so different scripts can handle different message functions, i.e for one script you want to log something to console and another evaluate the data returned.

Answer (score 2):

Use [send](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#communication-send) on Javascript side

In the python side

```py
f = open('/tmp/log', 'w')    
# ...
def on_message(msg, _data):
    f.write(msg['payload'] + '\n')
# ...
script.on('message', on_message)
# don't forget f.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new at this, I don't understand. Do I need to inject another script into my application process just write to return output? Because script.js is my script to intercept the function whenever it is called when the application is running. And is `script.on` suppose to return values that are sent back from the javascript side through `send`?

Comment: I cant seem to do it, i've updated the post with my script.js, after placing send, the value does not return back.